# Under what conditions for ai's will P=a1P1 + ... + akPk be a probability function?

Tags: probability, statistics

Full question:

Suppose $P_{1},...P_{k}$ are probability functinos on $\Omega$. Let $a_{1},...a_{k}$ be a sequence of numbers. Under what conditions on $a_{i}$s will:

P = $a_{1}P_{1} + ... + a_{k}P_{k}$

be a probability function?

--

I understand the three properties of a probability function and have been thinking of how to apply them to this question, but don't know how -- they're all related to the probability of a specific event(?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 \le a_i \le 1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i =1$ then the probability mass function defined as $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i P_k(x)=P(x)$ is also a probability mass function. You can verify the properties of a probability mass function for $P(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense :)